# Use qplot to draw only one subset of data

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, subset, r-factor

I have a list named `d` like this:

`V1` is an integer set from 0 - 50
`V2` is a real set from 1500 - 1800
`V3` is an integer set from 1 - 50

In total, the list contains 5100 objects

Now I would like to plot the histogram of `V2`, with `V1` = a certain number (0, 1 or 10, etc.)

I tried different ways:

```
factor(d$V1)
qplot(V2, data=d, V1 = 1)        --> not successful 
d.subset <- subset(d, d$V1 = 1)  --> not successful
```

I really get crazy with this. Check the characteristics of `d$V1` but found nothing strange. Anyone could help me out?

```
is.factor(d$V1) 

[1] TRUE

str(d$V1)  Factor w/ 51 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

levels(d$V1)  
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" 
[20] "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37""38" 
[39] "39" "40" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45" "46" "47" "48" "49" "50" "51"
```

Comment: Is `d` a list or a data frame? (What do you get when you try `dput(head(d))`?

Comment: If you move away from using `qplot`, to `ggplot() + geom_xxxx` then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431246/ignoring-one-of-the-factors-of-ggplot-in-r/14437598#14437598 will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line:

```
d.subset <- subset(d, d$V1 = 1)
```

to

```
d.subset <- subset(d, V1 == 1)
```

Notice the double equals (`==`) to denote the logical operator. `=` is used for assignment and doesn't subset the data frame.

Finally, you might mean to put the 1 in quotes if you want to get the `"1"` level of the factor (which might not be the same as the numeric `1`).

```
d.subset <- subset(d, V1 == "1")
```